# aspnet kendo sitemap (only) localization not working

Tags: asp.net, localization, kendo-ui, sitemap

I have a problem with sitemap localization. Whole app is localized properly but sitemap is not.

I would like to get any error information or know where to put breakpoint to know what is wrong.

I've been using this [guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178427.aspx)

E:
I forgot to mention that I'm using Kendo MVC Sitemap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that localization of kendo sitemap is not possible at all, and you have to make separate sitemaps for each language ...